# Having the section title from bottom to the top of the paper

Tags: floats

I am trying to have the section title from bottom to the top of the paper as I've attached the image. But somehow it did not work well.

```
\newpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\section{Appendix}

\begin{table}[]
\end{table}
```

Any idea how I can get it to the top?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried `\clearpage` instead `\newpage`?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  `table` is a floating object.  Try making the optional placement `[hb]` to omit the possibility of it being placed at the top of the page.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. @barbarabeeton's solution worked well!

Answer (score 1):

This page contains only two items -- a section heading and a floating table.

In the absence of a specified option, a float will preferentially be placed at the top of the page, in this case above the section heading.

An easy way to get around this problem is to specify an option.  Here, the option `[hb]` will omit trying to place the float at the top of the page.  If it doesn't fit "here", it will be deferred to the bottom of the next page.  (If the figure is very large, it would be a good idea to add "page" to the options: `[hbp]`.

A good general explanation of how floats are positioned is given here: [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017)